# need ideas on how to group this table

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, pivot

I have a raw data which looks like this
[image]

My goal is to group it by date,tktnum,username. The report should look like
[image]

The query I have cannot group it by username as there is another entry "HANK". I need to replace the username with the user who has a "START" value =1.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: postgresql, oracle, mysql...?

Comment: Done. I am using Oracle. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that you want to group by `date` and `tktnum`, and use a conditional expression to get the `username` from the record that has `start = 1`:

```
select
    date,
    tktnum,
    max(case when start = 1 then username end) username,
    max(referout)   referout,
    max(start)      start,
    max(seanr)      seanr,
    max(referback)  referback,
    max(condition1) condition1,
    max(condition2) condition2,
    max(condition3) condition3
from mytable
group by date, tktnum
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I've tried it out and just can't believe it was actually that simple hahahaha. Cheers!!!